# How do the default color, font family and font size for a TextBlock and Label get set in an WPF app?

Tags: wpf, windows, themes, label, textblock

Edit: I guess the question wasn't stated very clearly. It actually composes of 4 separate ones:

1. How does a `TextBlock` get its default color, if the client app doesn't provide any style, either programmatically or through xaml?
2. How does a `Label` get its default color?
3. How does a `TextBlock` get its default font size and font family, if the client app doesn't provide any style, either programmatically or through xaml?
4. How does a `Label` get its default font size and font family?

BTW, the questions are not about how to *change* or define styles for the color/font size/font family of a `TextBlock` or a `Label`, although they are somehow related. I think I already knew the answer for #2, that is a `Label` gets its color from [SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.controltextbrushkey.aspx) and by overriding `ConrolTextBrushKey` like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
```

You would be able to "globally" change color for `Label`s. After some research, I guess I also find the answer for #1: A `TextBlock` inherits the its foreground color from its containing `Window`, which by default gets its `Foreground` color from [SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.windowtextbrushkey.aspx). By defining a color for the WindowTextBrush like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}" 
                     Color="Yellow"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

You would be able to change the "foreground" color for the `TextBlock`s inside the `Window`.

Question #3 and #4 remain puzzles for me, but I am assuming they have to do with the [SystemFonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.aspx).

Hope this makes sense. I really like to know the answers as they have been bothering me for a while. Many thanks!

Below is the original post:

---

If you look into the style for a `Label` in the theme (for example "aero.normalcolor.xaml") that comes with Windows, you can find

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" 
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
```

Which sets the color for a `Label`. But there is no where the `FontSize` property is specified in the style, which I assume has something to do with the [SystemFonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.aspx). For a `TextBlock`, it looks even more mysterious as the style for it in "aero.normalcolor.xaml" has only 4 lines:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                        Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
                        Value="None"/>
    </Style>
```

Where does a `Label` or a `TextBlock` get the values for its color and font size/family from, if the app doesn't set any, and where are those hooks in WPF?

Edit:

This is a test drive attempting to set the `TextBlock` color through `SystemColors.ControlTextBrush` (assuming that's where a `TextBlock` gets its default color from, which seems to be false):

```
<Window x:Class="TestFontColor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="This is red."/>
    <Label Content="This is blue.">
        <Label.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
        </Label.Resources>
    </Label>
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock: This is still black."/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: After some digging around, I've found [TextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

As far as I remember, in most cases classes like `TextBlock`, `TextBox` and many others take the text color from the `TextElement.Foreground` property. The property value is inherited throughout the visual tree, i.e. you may set it on the root element and have most of the text change its color. For example:

```
<Grid TextElement.Foreground="Red">
  <TextBlock Text="test"/>
</Grid>
```

In fact, the same is true even for labels: the setter in their default style simply sets the `TextElement.Foreground` to one of the system colors.

However, this is true only for the default state of controls. Altered states, like highlighting, are not inherited, but rather taken from the system colors, as Rachel has written.

**UPDATE**

The same is true for `FontSize` and `FontFamily`. They are properties of the `TextElement` class that have attached property usage. They inherit their values. Once you set a value on a visual tree item, all its children will get the same value. Unless they override it either by an explicit property assignment, or by style and so on.

Once again, text color font size and font family are governed by the value of `TextElement.Foreground`, `TextElement.FontSize` and `TextElement.FontFamily` attached dependency properties on a specific visual element.

Some controls, like `Label` explicitly set their `Foreground` to some brush. It happens so that the brush is one of the `SystemColors`. But it doesn't have to be true for all controls. Others (`TextBlock`, `TextBox`, etc.) don't override the property value and just use some default settings evaluated on startup. The same happens to `FontSize` and `FontFamily`. **You do not need to set them wherever in order for them to work**. That's how WPF works.

Supposedly, the values depend on the system theme. I believe they are evaluated during the app startup. Perhaps they are configurable.

**UPDATE 2**

Answers to your new questions:

> How does a TextBlock get its default color, if the client app doesn't provide any style, either programmatically or through xaml?

It takes it from the inherited value of the `TextElement.Foreground` attached dependency property. By default it is inherited from the root visual element, which in turn is simply set to the default value of the dependency property (`Brushes.Black`). [See also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foreground.aspx)

> How does a Label get its default color?

It takes it from the value of the `TextElement.Foreground` attached dependency property. Since its default style sets it to the `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}`, it gets bound to the system color.

> How does a TextBlock get its default font size and font family, if the client app doesn't provide any style, either programmatically or through xaml?

The same as for its text color. MSDN says that for the default value of the font size is [SystemFonts.MessageFontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.messagefontsize.aspx) which depends on system settings. Font family is determined in similar way from [SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.messagefontfamily.aspx).
Both these default values are passed to the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructor upon dependency property registration in the `TextElement` static constructor.

Going deeper: `SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily` and `SystemFonts.MessageFontSize` wrap internal `SystemParameters.NonClientMetrics` which in turn are retrieved from the WIN32 native `SystemParametersInfo` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947. Thus the WPF is tightly integrated with all Windows UI stuff like themes, fonts, etc.

> How does a Label get its default font size and font family?

The same as for `TextBlock`. `Label` derives from `ContentControl` which in turn derives from `Control`. `Control` class adds itself as an owner of the `TextElement.FontFamily` and `TextElement.FontSize` properties with the same default values.

See also:

[Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx)

**UPDATE 3**

You should understand the main idea: the values are inherited. It means they might be inherited from anywhere, from any control. You can tell exactly which one it is inherited from only for a certain logical tree structure. You change it a bit - and the colors change. Someone sets a property's value explicitly - and all children will inherit the value. Therefore your questions make little practival sense. But they are still interesting from the perspective of undestanding the WPF.

**Overriding default values**

Although you cannot change the values of the `SystemFonts` properties (they are read-only), you don't have to. To change the font size and family for the whole window, simply assign the desired values to the `TextElement` attached properties on the `Window`:

```
<Window TextElement.FontSize="20" TextElement.FontFamily="Century Gothic">
  ..
</Window>
```

and all controls that do not explicitly override the inheritance will receive the settings. For those that do override - you'll have to override their default styles or even throw them away if they hard-code the values.

The same approach works for `TextElement.Foreground` (and `Background` and so on).

Comment: Please read the question before posting an answer. I don't believe either answer has provided any new information than that's already there in the original question. Many thanks.

Comment: Hope my comment didn't come through as rude; if that's the case, I am sorry.

Comment: @mobileTofu At this time I don't understand what your question is. Do you want to know why Labels behave differently from TextBlocks? Do you want to know how default colors and other settings are determined? Why aren't you satisfied with my or Rachel's answers?

Comment: @mobileTofu Please, see my UPDATE 2 for answers to your rephrased questions.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I guess I didn't state my questions clearly, which I updated (again), along with the attempt to answer them by myself. You said "You don't need to set those them wherever in order for them to work" and "supposedly depend on the system theme", I guess that's exactly where my puzzle is. I'd like to find out how the _system_ or the WPF _framework_ defines those default values, not about how the client app goes about providing its own to style a TextBlock or a Label control; although the two questions are somehow related. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update #3. I guess my questions could also be rephrased as to what sits on top of the inheritance trees for those properties (foreground/font size/family).

Comment: @mobileTofu Please, refer to my answers to your questions #3, 4 given in UPDATE 2. This answers them. I've also added more details on how the default settings of the WPF properties map to the WIN32 API functions ('Going deeper'). Check out if it is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like what I'm looking for. So how do I go about defining/changing MessageFontFamily and MessageFontSize so that I see a TextBlock or Label gets inherited, either through xaml, Windows GUI or programmatically?

Comment: Only TextElement.FontSize="xx" works. .FontFamily and .Foreground do not work.  e.g.

<Window TextElement.FontSize="16" TextElement.FontFamily="Comic Sans" TextElement.Foreground="Red">
   ...
</Window>

Answer (score 4):

The default colors are pulled from the operating system's settings.

You can overwrite them by creating a brush which has the a key that references a [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) brush key

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
```

Comment: SystemsColors doesn't seem to affect TextBlocks, though.

Comment: @mobileTofu You must be doing it wrong. Rachel is right, if you put her sample brush to a `ResourceDictionary` it will override system settings. Try using `ControlTextBrushKey` instead of `HighlightBrushKey` to increase the effect. Also, try putting the brush to a **higher-level logical tree item** than the controls you want it to affect. Resources of a `Label` won't affect the `Label`, only its children.

Comment: @Pavel Gatilov inline style resources for a Label do affect Label. Please see my edit above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

> By default, WPF uses the GlobalUserInterface.composite font in your Windows\Fonts directory.

And according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(v=vs.95).aspx

> A non-negative value that specifies the font size, measured in pixels. The default is 11.

In addition, you can find many of the other default values stored in various places in the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontstyle(v=VS.95).aspx for the style, which says:

> The requested font style, which is a FontStyle that is obtained from one of the FontStyles property values. The default is Normal.