# WPF Override Metadata Foreground Dependency Property

Tags: wpf

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on my problem as I've searched everywhere and can't find an explanation or solution to this.

To explain the problem I have created a class called Label which inherits from TextBlock and I want to override the default Foreground brush, Font Weight, Font Size and Font Family; all the overrides work apart from the Foreground (I can override the background without a problem so it is something specific to the foreground property).

Create a new WPF application and create this simple class: -

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class Label : TextBlock
    {
        static Label()
        {
            ForegroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red));
            FontWeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FontWeights.Bold));
            FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(50.0));
            FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Calibri")));
        }
    }
}
```

Create an instance of this new Label class in MainWindow.xaml: -

```
<Grid>
    <local:Label Text="TEST" />
</Grid>
```

You should see that the Label doesn't adopt the new Foreground default but looking in SNOOP it is still inheriting it's value.

As far as I'm aware any Dependency Property can be overridden so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: According to [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) value inheritance precedes a default value from property metadata. In contrast to `Background`, `Foreground` is a dependency property that inherits its value.

Comment: See also [Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But by overriding the property metadata you have the option to specify the PropertyMetadataOptions flags which I would have thought would allow you to remove inheritance but it does not.

Comment: But you haven't changed any flags. You would have to use a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructor with a flags parameter.

Comment: Although not shown in my example I had tried that and it does not work. It is something to do with the fact that inherited DPs have to be registered as attached (according to MSDN), there is clearly something more going on behind the scenes with inherited DPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is:

```
public class Label : TextBlock
    {
        static Label()
        {
            ForegroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red, OnForegroundChanged));
            FontWeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FontWeights.Bold));
            FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(50.0));
            FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Calibri")));
        }

        private static void OnForegroundChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        MethodInfo mi = typeof(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs).GetMethod("get_OperationType",
                                                                              BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                              BindingFlags.Instance);
        var v = mi.Invoke(e, null);

        if ((e.NewValue != Brushes.Red) && (v.ToString() == "Inherit"))
        {
            ((Label)d).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            ((Label)d).Foreground = (Brush)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

On VisualStudio 2012 in the design view the preview of you code show the text in red color. Something change it at runtime. But at the moment I can't tell you who and why... The dafault inherited value prevales!

Edit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630868/520612) some good info.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful link and also your work around to the problem. I was hoping to not have to hack something into the property changed callback but no other solution is available at present.

Comment: Ingenious use of reflection to get hold of the inherit info; I thought that: -

DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(dependencyObject, e.Property).BaseValueSource

Might have been set to inherited avoiding the need for reflection but instead it shows as DefaultStyle

Comment: Yes.  The private method get_OperationType is the only way to detect the first change foreground color. Best design is to put reflection out of the callback event and here just use his value!

Answer (score 5):

```
ForegroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LcdTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime)) { Inherits = false });
```

This works for me.