# How can I override the default value of a BackgroundProperty in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am building a custom WPF control. In this control I want to override the default value of the BackgroundProperty, so that all instances of the control will have a gray background. To achieve this, I have a static constructor in the control, with the following content:

```
static CustomControl() {
    CustomControl.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(CustomControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray)
    );
}
```

However, when testing the control, the background is still set to transparent, even though I have not specified any value of the Background property in the XAML:

```
 <c:CustomControl />
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: some xaml would be usefull i think

Comment: read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14142305/520612

Answer (score 2):

Your property override is the correct approach. However, your control template needs to actually use the `Background` property. You have not showed us your template, but it would need to include something like this:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...
```

EDIT: I think your question is creating confusion because you say custom control, when you may have actually meant custom *user* control. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kent! I am creating a custom ScatterView control (lets call this CustomScatterView) that extends the ScatterView control by adding drag and drop support. My template for the CustomScatterView control is empty, as I do not wish to add any additional UI elements to the control. However, I would like to change the default background color of the CustomScatterView. Maybe I'm approaching this in the wrong way though..